# Sublime C++ pointer support

Tags: c++, clang, sublimetext2

```
class Test
{
public:

    int i;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Test *i = new Test;
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to get support for the arrow notation? So if I write `i.` it automatically gets expand to `i->`

I am using SublimeClang. If something like this doesn't exist, would it be possible it create such a plugin?

Comment: Something wrong with typing one extra character? It's not like pointers should be used as often as possible anyway.

Comment: it's huge problem, but if such a plugin would exist, I would definitely´use it. It's 3 keystrokes vs 1.

Comment: It is something that Qt Creator does.

Comment: @VladLazarenko Exactly, I am used to QtCreator but I want to use sublime now and I really miss this feature.

Comment: @MaikKlein: Just out of curiosity, what's there in Sublime that makes you move? Among editors and open-source IDEs, Qt Creator has the best semantics support to date. Only latest Xcode can beat it. Just curious.

Comment: @VladLazarenko I have not much experience with qtcreator but it is a really good ide and I know that. But I just saw Sublimetext2 with awesome snippet support and runtime error highlighting https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qsaEnSRzRpU - I am also using several other languages and I want to start getting proficient in one IDE/Editor.

Comment: And there are tons plugins that make your life easier + detailed documentation. But I am still not 100% sure how viable it really is to write c++ code compared to a full feature IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) for windows, using this [tutorial](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm). or on Linux use [Autokey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/), by following this [tutorial](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/07/automatic-text-replacement-application.html).

However, how hard can typing one extra character be as chris said? What if not everything is a pointer?

Comment: True, but what do you do when you want a dot? Surely not everything is a pointer!

Comment: @chris, that is true, but judging from Op's question he doesn't use dots.

Comment: @Link: Really? He does. This is a very useful feature, actually, but requires an editor to understand C++ semantics.

Comment: @VladLazarenko Well I know it's useful. I use them. Three in this sentence. I was just answering the op's question. And yes, I understand C++ semantics.

Comment: @Link: I meant that editor must understand semantics... I think a question is pretty clear as to what is being asked about, and it certainly not about automatic replacements of `.` with `->` for everything...

Comment: @VladLazarenko, ah, I get it so, it would only trigger in certain cases or something?

Comment: @Link: Exactly. When you are trying to access a member of an class through an object pointer and mistakenly use operator `.` instead of `->` :)